# Perl find the elements that appears once in an array

Tags: perl

Given an array of elements, how to find the element that occurs once only in that array:

```
my @array = qw(18 1 18 3 18 1 1 2 3 3);
```

result should be: 2

Comment: Please show your working - SO isn't a code writing service. As a starter for 10 I'll offer: use a hash, because hashes are good for finding uniques. And also - don't use `qw` with comma separated values - that's just dirty.

Comment: You need to traverse through the array, compare the first element in array with the rest of the elements in the list if they are equal. If equal, move to the next element. If you do not find an element that matches or equal to current element, then you add that unique element in a new array of unique elements. Then print out your result.

Comment: @Juniar: No. In Perl, you'd use a hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a variation on [perlfaq5 - How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f)

Just use a hash to count the elements, and then print the ones seen only once.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(18 1 18 3 18 1 1 2 3 3);

my @nondup = do {
    my %count;
    $count{$_}++ for @array;
    grep {$count{$_} == 1} keys %count;
};

print "@nondup\n";
```

Outputs:

```
2
```

Comment: just for kicks, the one-liner: `my @nondup = map keys %{$_->{unique}||{}}, List::Util::reduce { $a->{seen}{$b}++ ? delete $a->{unique}{$b} : undef $a->{unique}{$b}; $a } {}, @array;`

Comment: @ysth Or a slight variation on ridiculousness: `my @nondup = map { my $h = $_; ( grep { $h->{$_} == 1 } keys %$h ) } List::Util::reduce { $a->{$b}++; $a } {}, @array;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this in simple way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = qw(7 8 7 5 18 1 18 3 18 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7);
my $tm = "";
my %hash=();
foreach $tm(@array){    
    if(exists $hash{$tm}){
        $hash{$tm} = "";
    }
    else{
        $hash{$tm} = "$tm";     
    }
}
print join ("\n", values %hash);exit;
```