# Perl find the elements that appears once in every array from the particular file using a function and an argument

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Good Morning everyone,
I want to find a element that appear once in every array from the particular file
So in each line it contain bbb\bbb\ddd so the output will be bbb on what line is it.
I made a function on every array from each line and perform hashing to print the element that appear once in the array.
I also want to pass the argument to the function. the argument is the array from one line. I found similar topics
[Perl find the elements that appears once in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937725/perl-find-the-elements-that-appears-once-in-an-array)
[get the value which is not the same from the row which has duplicate in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312299/get-the-value-which-is-not-the-same-from-the-row-which-has-duplicate-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment79594135_46312299)

my code below

perl.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $fh, "<content.txt") or die "Could Not Open the file content.txt\n";
while (my @array = <$fh>)
{
        getOnceData(@array);
}
function getOnceData
{
        chomp;
        my (@array) = @_; this is an argument
        @array = split /\\/; #split the \ and pour all the content into the array
        my %count;
        $count{$_}++ for @array;
        print {$count{$_} == 1} keys %count;

}
1;
```

content.txt

```
aaa\bbb\aaa
cccd\ade\ade
ppp\www\ppp
www\aaa\www\aaa
```

I have a lot of error.... the error say

```
syntax error at getoncedata.pl line 13, near "my "
Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at getoncedata.pl line 13.
Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at getoncedata.pl line 14.
Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at getoncedata.pl line 16.
syntax error at getoncedata.pl line 18, near "}"
```

I research the error for global symbol and they said to use my for that error.
I did put "my" for global symbol @array

Background information:
Make a function to check every array on each line which has element that appear once.
I made a code to open the file and in each line i accessed the line as an argument and call the function

Comment: Erm i did ask question on how to show element that appears one on each line. For example aaa\bbb\bbb out put aaa on line 1

Comment: Didn't we [do this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312299/get-the-value-which-is-not-the-same-from-the-row-which-has-duplicate-in-perl/46316737)? And have you changed your username again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $fh, "<", "content.txt")
   or die("Can't open file \"content.txt\": $!\n");

while (my $line = <$fh>)  # Read the file line by line
{
        chomp $line;  # Remove trailing newline char
        getOnceData($line);  # Pass each lines to getOnceData
}

# Perl has no syntax called `function`
# What you need is `sub`
sub getOnceData
{
        my $line = shift;
        my @array = split /\\/, $line; #split the \ and pour all the content into the array
        my %count;
        $count{$_}++ for @array;
        print grep {$count{$_} == 1} keys %count;  # Don't forget to grep
        print "\n";  # Add newline char

}
```

Comment: @Azhar, If that's all you took from that answer, you missed out on a lot!

Comment: I did split the array. I performed the hash to find element which appears once in every array

Comment: Number found where operator expected at getoncedata.pl line 20, near "1"
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at getdifference.pl line 14, near "my "
Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at getoncedata.pl line 14.
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at getoncedata.pl line 14.
Global symbol "@array" requires explicit package name at getoncedata.pl line 16.
syntax error at getoncedata.pl line 19, near "}"
Execution of getoncedata.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Azhar, You miscopied something. Try again.

Comment: can i use @_ instead of shift

Comment: @Azhar, like `my ($line) = @_;` ?